# Ошибка после смены версии PHP

Tags: php, php7

После смены версии PHP с 5.4 на 7.0 появилась ошибка:

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; Browser has a deprecated
>   constructor in /home/u408663914/public_html/core/class/browser.php on
>   line 135

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить!

> Строка 135: `class Browser {`

Весь код файла: http://ideone.com/CcefNk

Comment: `public function Browser` замените на `public function __construct`

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в **самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас в классе есть метод с таким же названием как и класс:

```
public function Browser($useragent="") {
    $this->reset();
    if( $useragent != "" ) {
        $this->setUserAgent($useragent);
    }
    else {
        $this->determine();
    }
}
```

Уже давно так не рекомендуют делать, вместо этого используйте магический метод `__construct`:

```
public function __construct($useragent="") {
    $this->reset();
    if( $useragent != "" ) {
        $this->setUserAgent($useragent);
    }
    else {
        $this->determine();
    }
}
```

UPD. Как верно подметил [@xEdelweiss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7017/xedelweiss) если используете сторонюю [библиотеку](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php/blob/master/lib/Browser.php), то лучше обновите её, вместо того чтобы самому менять исходный код.

Comment: Или, так как класс чужой, его можно обновить: [Browser.php](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php/blob/master/lib/Browser.php)

Answer (score 2):

Вам следует использовать более новую версию библиотеки, которая к тому же умеет определять и делать то, что ваша - устаревшая - не умеет.

[Скачать новую версию можно здесь.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cbschuld/Browser.php/master/lib/Browser.php)